# Tagging/Pushing a docker image to a registry running local on a UNIX domain socket

Tags: docker, push, docker-registry, unix-socket

I have created a docker registry in my local machine (Ubuntu) using the docker-registry package listening an UNIX domain socket with the following configuration:

```
 version: 0.1
 log:
 fields:
  service: registry
 http:
   addr: /var/run/my.sock
   net: unix
   headers:
     X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
 health:
   storagedriver:
     enabled: true
     interval: 10s
     threshold: 3
 storage:
   filesystem:
     rootdirectory: /some/path
```

Now I am trying to tag some docker images and push them to that registry. However I don't what tag I should give to the images. I have tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
docker tag busybox localhost/tmp/my.sock/busybox
docker push localhost/var/run/my.sock/busybox
```

but it doesn't work:

```
The push refers to a repository [localhost/var/run/my.sock/busybox]
Put http://localhost/v1/repositories/var/run/my.sock/busybox/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?